# drawRect is not working In Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Hi i m adding UIView to window.

this view has drawRect as-

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {


        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

          CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 300, 400);

        CGContextStrokePath(context);

}
```

but this code is not drawing any line.
so any help for this??????

Comment: You'll save yourself a world of pain if you just read the formatting instructions right next to the question box as you edit. Indent code by four spaces (and no need for `<br>` on every line).

Comment: I don't know if it's necessary, but it's probably a good idea to call one of the `CGContextSetStrokeColor...` functions.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
```

after your code.

Comment: I have tried this also- CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

          CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 300, 400);

        CGContextStrokePath(context);                                        CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke);
But it's not displaying anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think Marcelo Cantos is right. You should set stroke color.
Maybe you can try this to set color.

```
[[UIColor blackColor] set];
```